# Component template should contain exactly one root element nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm not sure what could be the issue here but I'm using nuxt to make a SPA app. and I'm getting an error from an already compiled piece of code I got from codepen. link to codepen

https://codepen.io/jjelic/pen/yevNLZ?editors=1010

When I try this code my my nuxt app I get an error. 
I've added a file called monitor.vue in pages folder and added the html and js like so

Is this root element error common as I have never encountered it before with html and how can I avoid?

```js
Vue.filter('currencyDisplay', {
  // model -> view
  read: function(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
      return accounting.formatMoney(val, "$", 2, ".", ",");
    }
  },
  // view -> model
  write: function(val, oldVal) {
    return accounting.unformat(val, ",");
  }
});

Vue.directive('sortable', {
  twoWay: true,
  deep: true,
  bind: function() {
    var that = this;

    var options = {
      draggable: Object.keys(this.modifiers)[0]
    };

    this.sortable = Sortable.create(this.el, options);
    console.log('sortable bound!')

    this.sortable.option("onUpdate", function(e) {
      that.value.splice(e.newIndex, 0, that.value.splice(e.oldIndex, 1)[0]);
    });

    this.onUpdate = function(value) {
      that.value = value;
    }
  },
  update: function(value) {
    this.onUpdate(value);
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [
      //initial data
      {
        qty: 5,
        description: "Something",
        price: 55.20,
        tax: 10
      },
      {
        qty: 2,
        description: "Something else",
        price: 1255.20,
        tax: 20
      },
    ],
    total: 0,
    grandtotal: 0,
    taxtotal: 0,
    delivery: 40
  },
  computed: {
    total: function() {
      var t = 0;
      $.each(this.rows, function(i, e) {
        t += accounting.unformat(e.total, ",");
      });
      return t;
    },
    taxtotal: function() {
      var tt = 0;
      $.each(this.rows, function(i, e) {
        tt += accounting.unformat(e.tax_amount, ",");
      });
      return tt;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function(index) {
      try {
        this.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, {});
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
    removeRow: function(index) {
      this.rows.splice(index, 1);
    },
    getData: function() {
      $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          rows: this.rows,
          total: this.total,
          delivery: this.delivery,
          taxtotal: this.taxtotal,
          grandtotal: this.grandtotal,
        },
        url: "/api/data"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="panel-body" id="app">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 20px;">No.</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th style="width: 80px;">Qty</th>
          <th style="width: 130px;" class="text-right">Price</th>
          <th style="width: 90px;">Tax</th>
          <th style="width: 130px;">Total</th>
          <th style="width: 130px;"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody v-sortable.tr="rows">
        <tr v-for="row in rows" track-by="$index">
          <td>
            {{ $index +1 }}
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control" v-model="row.description" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control" v-model="row.qty" number />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control text-right" v-model="row.price | currencyDisplay" number data-type="currency" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="row.tax">
              <option value="0">0%</option>
              <option value="10">10%</option>
              <option value="20">20%</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="form-control text-right" :value="row.qty * row.price | currencyDisplay" v-model="row.total | currencyDisplay"
              number readonly />
            <input type="hidden" :value="row.qty * row.price * row.tax / 100" v-model="row.tax_amount | currencyDisplay"
              number />
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" @click="addRow($index)">add row</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="removeRow($index)">remove row</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-right">TAX</td>
          <td colspan="1" class="text-right">{{ taxtotal | currencyDisplay }}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-right">TOTAL</td>
          <td colspan="1" class="text-right">{{ total | currencyDisplay }}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-right">DELIVERY</td>
          <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><input class="form-control text-right" v-model="delivery | currencyDisplay"
              number /></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-right"><strong>GRANDTOTAL</strong></td>
          <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>{{ grandtotal = total + delivery | currencyDisplay }}</strong></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <button @click="getData()">SUBMIT DATA</button>
    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your HTML snippet appears to be for a component but your script creates a new `Vue` instance bound to the `#app` element. That doesn't seem right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is actually a very simple problem. I don't know vue, but the render method has the same limits of react's one: every component **must** have only one root element in its template.

This means that a situation like this isn't accepted:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

But like this is correct:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
```

This means that surely, somehow in the code you didn't show us, you're putting two elements as root of your template

Comment: @Phil yes, exactly for this reason I wrote "somehow in the code you didn't show us", because I'm strongly convinced that he has two root elements in the code he's running, because from the code he posted, if you ask me, there is no reason why it should give this error :)

Comment: I deleted a hello world test in another file which was directed to another url that was causing the same issue. This root element error has gone way. I've a new error with the above code  ` - :value="row.qty * row.price | currencyDisplay" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally`
Could this be due to selecting single page app with nuxt?

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone I'm out, this one is all yours

Comment: @tomoc4 please, I know it's difficult nowadays to get answered in stackoverflow, but asking more in the comments it's not manageable. Since your code raised a new error, I kindly ask if you could open a new issue and mark this one as resolved.
Plus I know no vue, I'm an angular/react dev :)

Comment: @Giaomo Cerquone Noted. Thanks for letting me know what causes the error. I will mark as resolved. Thanks